# Receiving events in Pusher client

Tags: python, websocket, pusher

I'm trying to connect to the [BitStamp Websocket API](https://www.bitstamp.net/websocket/) with Python.

However, I cannot find a decent tutorial or explanation of the process anywhere.

**What I need is to receive the live price ticker.**

I tried using [this](https://github.com/ekulyk/PythonPusherClient) library but I'm not receiving any live price. I think I'm probably missing something because I'm new with WebSockets.

Here is my code:

```
import pusherclient
import sys

# Add a logging handler so we can see the raw communication data
import logging
root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.INFO)
ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
root.addHandler(ch)

global pusher

# We can't subscribe until we've connected, so we use a callback handler
# to subscribe when able
def connect_handler(data):
    channel = pusher.subscribe('live_trades')
    channel.bind('trade', callback)

appkey = "de504dc5763aeef9ff52"
pusher = pusherclient.Pusher(appkey)
pusher.connection.bind('pusher:connection_established', connect_handler)
pusher.connect()

print("finished")
```

All I see when I run this code is - Finished

**How can I receive live updates on the price?**

Comment: Have you found a better way of getting the data then via the Streamhandler?

Comment: FYI that according to [Pusher API](https://pusher.com/docs/libraries#community-py) the Python client library is a fork of that repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a while loop at the end of the code:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```